# Is OpenSSL validation affected by line endings?

Tags: php, openssl, sign, verify

Is OpenSSL affected by the kind of line endings a text has CR+LF or LF?

Also is it affected by any a text having or not any empty lines at the end?

I an trying to validate something and I am not exactly sure how to prepare the text for verification what kind of line endings to have and if I should or not trim it beforehand.

The text was transmitted via multiple relays and i am no longer sure if the line endings are the same way as they wore when it was signed.

I know the validation should be successful but I cannot get that result and I have tryed every possible combination I could think of.

Comment: I don't suppose you could post some code?

Comment: That is irrelevant to my question. Take the PHP openssl_verify() function as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signature proves the integrity of a file down to the last bit.  If one bit of the file changes, the signature will not verify, thus proving the file has been tampered with.

So to answer your question, if a file was signed and subsequently the line endings changed, then yes, the validation will fail.